# Drupal schema for text_with_summary in install file

Tags: drupal, installation, drupal-schema

I'm a drupal newbie.  In Drupal 7, I have an install file and I'm trying to get the schema to work for a text_with_summary.

Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way but I am using a form's install file to create the databases I will need.  I just can't seem to get the "body" (called another name) field to work with text_with_summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am using a form's install file to create the databases I will need.

Do you mean a module's install file (not being picky just trying to make sure we're talking about the same thing)?

`text_with_summary` is not valid in a Drupal database schema (unless you're talking about a field schema but you surely would have mentioned that if you were). All valid field types for `hook_schema()` are listed on the [Schema API page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7). `text_with_summary` is a widget type, not a database field type.

Posting some code would help an awful lot in trying to work out what you're trying to accomplish.

**UPDATE**

This will declare a table with an ID field and a text column suitable for holding the rich text you need:

```
function MYMODULE_schema() {
  $schema['my_table'] = array(
    'description' => 'Table description',
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'type' => 'serial',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE
      ),
      'text_column' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => TRUE
      )
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id')
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

The [Schema API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--schema.inc/group/schemaapi/7) is in invaluable reference page for this sort of thing.

When you want to display your form you'll probably want to look at the [Form API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7), particularly the [drupal_get_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) function.

Hope that helps, downloading the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples) would also be a very good idea, it has tons of well documented Drupal code examples.

Comment: Wow - thanks for answering so fast.  You're already making it clearer.  OK - so text_with_summary is not valid in schemas (which explains why I was not able to find it searching).

Comment: No problem I use Drupal for a large part of my working life, what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Wow-thanks for answering so fast. I didn't realize it wasn't a valid field schema-which explains why I couldn't find it searching. Yes, I do mean a module's install file:) What I'm trying to do is prepare a table with the fields I will need, one of which is I'm used to calling a "rich-text" field but is the same type as a Body field in Drupal.  Several steps later, when other fields are populated, a user would get this field in a form.  I apologize in advance for my terminology - I'm still getting used to "drupalese".  So is what I'm looking for is accomplished with a text type field?

Comment: Sorry I'm still not really sure what you're trying to do when you say you're trying to prepare a table do you mean a database table?

Comment: Yes - a database table.  I'm not populating all of it yet - just creating the columns for later use.

Comment: OK I think I get it, I'll update the previous answer with some code that might help